# How to set the collection view cell size exactly equal to the collection view in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to set a collection view where it is only displayed one element at the time and it scrolls horizontally. I want to know how to set the same size for both if the collection view has equal width with the superview (phone size).

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can set the itemSize equal to the collection view size, and set the collection view contentInset (0,0,0,0), and set the flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing=0.

Comment: Code uploaded.let me know code works for you...

Answer (score 7):

**Simple answer :**

Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your class
and then use this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: yourCollectionView.bounds.width, height: yourCollectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

to make it horizontal:

[image]

Comment: You can simply return `collectionView.bounds.size`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add it programmatically you can try this:

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.isPagingEnabled = true
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return cv
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

To set collectionView scroll Direction  Programmically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
       layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    }
    }
```

To set collectionView layout

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
      layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
      layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
      layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
      layout.invalidateLayout()

      return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height:(self.view.frame.height) // Set your item size here
     }
```

**Note**: Layout works tested in Swift 3. But, I want you to consider using page view instead.If you not passing any data from CollectionView.